# Spring Mockito @BeforeAll mocking logic works on 1 test only

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, testing, mockito

I have a problem with understanding why the logic mocked inside **@BeforeAll** works, but only for the first test.
They work fine separately, copying the identical logic to both tests will produce the same result - 1 passed, 1 failed. *What happens:* in AboutUsService.update() on the first line appears the mistake at

> pageRepository.getByName(ABOUT_US_PAGE).orElseThrow(null);

For the first test, the calling of the method produces the expected result and returns AboutUsPage with its data. But for the next one it produces ***Optional.empty***
and NullPointerException eventually. What is the trick, why mocking works only for one test?
Also, I checked out if the real repository is getting called, but it seems like something else caused it.
Changing the annotation to **@BeforeEach** solves this problem, but shouldn't it work as well with **@BeforeAll**? Spring Boot v. 2.3.4

```
@SpringBootTest(classes = {AboutUsService.class, AboutUsPageRepository.class,
    AboutUsPageImageStore.class, ImageUtil.class})
@TestInstance(Lifecycle.PER_CLASS)
public class AboutUsServiceTest {

  @Autowired
  private AboutUsService aboutUsService;

  @MockBean
  private AboutUsPageRepository pageRepository;

  @MockBean
  private AboutUsPageImageStore aboutUsPageImageStore;

  @MockBean
  private ImageUtil imageUtil;

  @BeforeAll
  public void configure() {
    when(pageRepository.getByName(anyString()))
        .thenReturn(Optional.of(AboutUsTestData.getAboutUsPage()));

    when(aboutUsPageImageStore.setContent(any(AboutUsPageImage.class), any(Resource.class)))
        .thenReturn(new AboutUsPageImage());
  }

  @Test
  public void updateWithImagesTest() {
    when(imageUtil.fileIsValid(any(MultipartFile.class)))
        .thenReturn(true);

    MultipartFile validFile = new MockMultipartFile("name", "etc", "content", "Hello".getBytes());
    aboutUsService.update(new MultipartFile[]{validFile});
    verify(pageRepository, times(1)).save(any(AboutUsPage.class));
  }

  @Test
  public void updateWithNoImagesTest() {
    AboutUsPage updated = aboutUsService.update(new MultipartFile[0]);
    AboutUsPage expected = AboutUsTestData.getAboutUsPage();
    assertSame(expected.getImages().size(), updated.getImages().size());
  }

}


@Service
@AllArgsConstructor
@Slf4j
public class AboutUsService {

  public static final String ABOUT_US_PAGE = "ABOUT_US_PAGE";

  private final AboutUsPageImageStore pageImageStore;
  private final ImageUtil imageUtil;
  private final AboutUsPageRepository pageRepository;

  @Transactional
  public AboutUsPage update(MultipartFile[] images) {
    AboutUsPage page = pageRepository.getByName(ABOUT_US_PAGE).orElseThrow(null);

    if (ArrayUtils.isNotEmpty(images)) {
      List<AboutUsPageImage> pageImages = new ArrayList<>();
      Arrays.stream(images).forEach(extraImage -> {
        if (imageUtil.fileIsValid(extraImage)) {
          AboutUsPageImage infoImage = new AboutUsPageImage();
          pageImageStore.setContent(infoImage, extraImage.getResource());
          infoImage.setPage(page);
          pageImages.add(infoImage);
        }
      });

      if (CollectionUtils.isNotEmpty(pageImages)) {
        page.setImages(pageImages);
      }
      return pageRepository.save(page);

    } else {
      return page;
    }
  }
}


@Repository
public interface AboutUsPageRepository extends JpaRepository<AboutUsPage, Long> {

  Optional<AboutUsPage> getByName(String name);

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`@BeforeAll` is executed once, before any test is executed. If you need logic that is executed before every test, use `@Before`

Comment: Thank you, I thought that we can execute this logic just once and avoid running it before each test

Comment: You won't see a difference as its const is miniscule in your case.

Comment: I still don't understand, because I thought `when().thenReturn()` configures the mock. So it would be enough to just configure it once before all tests? Why do I have to repeat that?

Comment: Most probably, runner is reseting all mocks between tests which makes a lot of sense in shared test context :)